# Problemas con AJAX y PHP

Tags: php, ajax, post

Me encuentro en un problema ya que estoy pasando un par de parametros de AJAX a PHP pero PHP, no recoge éstos datos.

```
function ImprimirFichaUsuario(){

    var id = $('#idusuarionuevo').val();
    var name = $('#nombrenuevo').val();

    //Estos alerts funcionan, sacan los valores, es decir el problema está mas adelante
    alert(id);
    alert(name);

    var params = {
        "id" : id,
        "noim" : name
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/app/mantenimientos/phpcontrolusuarios/imprimir.ficha.php",
        data  : params,
        dataType: "json",
        encode: true
    })
    .done(function(data){
    ...
    });}
```

Y en imprimir.ficha.php tengo esto:

```
<?php  

$id = $_POST['id'];
$nombre = $_POST['noim'];

echo "ID: ";
echo $id;
echo "y nombre ";
echo $nombre;     <?
```

Al ver que responde este archivo, me encuentro que no recibe bien los datos por POST.
¿Alguna idea?
Muchas gracias de antemano
Un saludo,
Iván.

**EDIT:**

Muchas gracias a todos! Ya lo tengo, me funcionaron todos los consejos, sobretodo el de juank, pero gracias a Kevin y a OscarGarcia por recomendar esa otra forma. Lo que más me sirvió fue el console.log en respuesta a AJAX. Ahi me di cuenta que si recogía bien los datos, y el que los trataba mal en el PHP era yo xD. Un saludo y gracias!!!

Comment: Cierra bien el PHP es así <?php codigo ?>
luego haz <?php vardump($_POST); ?>
a ver que pasa un saludo.

Comment: Buenas juank, el PHP estaba bien cerrado solo que al escribirlo aqui se me fue la olla y lo cerré mal jeje. En relación al var_dump sale esto: array(0) { }. Alguna recomendación??

Comment: una segunda solucion es enviarle variable por variable, 
´$.post("tu.php", {id:id,name:name},function(respuesta){console.log(respues);}´ y en teoria deberia de funcionar

Comment: Buenas, el console.log me devuelve bien la respuesta, pero si veo la salida del php, no es la misma respuesta. PHP sigue sin "leer bien" los datos por POST, pero el caso es que la respuesta, dice que si. No entiendo...

Comment: Un pequeño comentario acerca de tu recomendación de cerrar bien el script PHP. A parte de que es algo opcional, [PSR-2 recomienda no cerrarlo](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#22-files) cuando el archivo contiene únicamente código PHP.

Comment: Abre la consola del navegador y haz la petición ajax, ahí puedes verificar que se está enviando y de que manera. Por otro lado si no vas a devolver una respuesta json elimina o comenta para las pruebas la opción `dataType: "json"`

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos! Ya lo tengo, me funcionaron todos los consejos, sobretodo el de juank, pero gracias a Kevin y a OscarGarcia por recomendar esa otra forma.
Lo que más me sirvió fue el console.log en respuesta a AJAX.
Ahi me di cuenta que si recogía bien los datos, y el que los trataba mal en el PHP era yo xD.
Un saludo y gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu `ajax` agrega `JSON.stringify(params)`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/app/mantenimientos/phpcontrolusuarios/imprimir.ficha.php",
    data  : JSON.stringify(params),
    dataType: "json",
    encode: true
})
```

y en tu `php`

```
$parametros = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Y luego lo trabajas como objeto de esta forma:

```
$id = $parametros->id;
$nombre = $parametros->noim;
```

Comment: Sólo un detalle. El código que has puesto (`json_decode($_POST);`) no funciona como esperas, debes hacer uso de `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));`.

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia por recordarme, se me paso esa parte importante.

Comment: Buenas, el $id y $nombre, viendo en la consola web que se pasan correctamente, se le puede hacer un echo, o no? Es que creo que estoy intentando mostrarlo por echo y no me funciona, pero los datos al usarlos funcionan...un saludo

Comment: Disculpa la demora @SrMcLister, si puedes usar echo, pero tienes que retornar un json ejemplo `echo json_encode($parametros);
`